# Create network user with remote home folder

Tags: macos, network, user-account, server.app, open-directory

I have Mac Server with OpenDirectory configured. Then I create some network users with home folder located on server. Due to the high bandwidth of user usage, I want to add another server that only host user home folders, so the traffic transferred between user and new server while authentication still via old server.
Is this possible to do that? If not, is there any walk around that fix my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. When prompted for the location of the home folder for the user you can choose any shared folder that you have configured to be used as storage for home folders in the File Sharing service. This folder can be anywhere on the machine or anywhere on the network.

Comment: 1. In Server.app, when editing user, I can choose only Local/None or shared folder on the MacServer.
2. If I mount the network folder to Mac Server, then choose it as home folder for network user, the traffic from client will transit via Mac Server to the shared folder. That means Mac Server still waste its bandwidth.
3. I use Workgroup Manager to edit user home folder to "afp://files_server/mount_point", but then couldn't login. It show error: You are unable to log in to the user account... at this time. Logging in to the account failed because and error occoured. => It seems couldn't mount

Comment: Thank you @grgarside, I did it, I type the wrong Full path for user homedir in Workgroup Manager.